# Why did MS-DOS applications built using Turbo Pascal fail to start with a division by zero error on faster systems?

Tags: ibm-pc, pascal, borland, delay-loop

On faster MS-DOS systems, it wasn't entirely uncommon for applications built using Borland's Turbo Pascal to fail to start, and (before exiting back to the command prompt) to report a division by zero error immediately upon launch.

As I recall, this behavior could be observed even with simple "Hello world" style programs.

Patches were available which fixed the issue both for freshly built executables as well as already-built ones, but my question here is: **What actually caused the error in the first place?**

A great answer will also discuss **what the fix was, and how it fit into the executable code without requiring a recompilation.**

Comment: I found my sources for a TSR tool that automatically detects affected real-mode Turbo Pascal program on load and patches them accordingly (so no modification is of on-disk EXE files is needed). Alas, only in its most recent version that includes a failed experiment to add protected mode support, and completely in German. It completely replaces `Delay` by a new, multitasking-friendly (for long delays) implementation. Is RCSE interested in that tool? Should I go polish it up?

Comment: @Michael there are a number of TSRs available, see [here](http://www.reimagery.com/fsfd/system.htm#pascalfix); if yours is different I guess it could be interesting!

Comment: Related, [What did the 'turbo' button actually do?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11056)

Comment: How about a patcher that would nix the initialization routine and replace the delay function with a version tweaked for the platform running the patcher?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Turbo Pascal programs start by calibrating a delay loop (so that the `Delay` function knows how much to spin to achieve a certain delay). The calibration counts the number of times a certain loop is run for 55ms (as measurable using the PC’s timer interrupt with its default setting), then divides the number of loops by 55 so that `Delay` can then busy-wait in millisecond increments. On fast CPUs, 200MHz and up (on Intel CPUs), the loop runs too many times, and the division overflows. The CPU throws a “divide overflow” error, which the Pascal runtime reports as a division by zero error.

There are quite a few sites which explain this and provide patches; for example, [J R Stockton’s page on the topic](http://ss64.net/merlyn/pas-r200.htm), which says

> The Borland Crt unit is included in the TURBO.TPL & TPP.TPL libraries; its initialisation routine will be linked if Crt is cited in a uses clause. The problem lies in the initialisation of Crt.Delay, but will appear if the Crt unit is cited regardless of whether Delay or any other Crt routine is called.
>
> During Crt unit initialisation, a loop executed for 55 ms increments a counter. Up to and in TP6, this was a 16-bit counter, and would happily overflow on a PC above about 20 MHz, leading to subsequent incorrect delays.
>
> The counter in TP7 & BP7 is now 32-bit, and should not itself overflow until processor speeds reach the 100 GHz region. But the count is divided by 55, and if the result cannot fit into a 16-bit word, the CPU raises a "divide overflow" error. This is reported by Borland as a "divide by zero" error, Runtime Error 200, since the only way that a user's Pascal code can cause a divide overflow is by dividing by zero.

(As [pointed out by Peter Cordes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12111/why-did-ms-dos-applications-built-using-turbo-pascal-fail-to-start-with-a-divisi/12112?noredirect=1#comment37865_12112), the last sentence is incorrect; it’s easy to cause a divide overflow using integer division in Pascal. Borland’s runtime does however report that as a “divide by zero” error.)

Arguably the best fix is to fix the Crt unit, and relink Pascal program. There are various approaches; for example, increasing the space allocated for the delay counter in `CRT.ASM`:

```
DelayCnt        DD      ?
```

(instead of `DW`), then altering the calibration routine to use both words instead of a single word.

*Patching* a fix into existing executables isn’t all that obvious since the fixed calibration routines take more space than the original, but that’s exactly what [Andreas Bauer’s patch](http://ss64.net/merlyn/pas-r200.htm#tppatch) (available on [SAC](https://www.sac.sk/download/utilprog/tppatch.zip), [Garbo](http://www.retroarchive.org/garbo/pc/turbopa7/tppatch.zip), or [manassehkatz’s site](https://smartcomputerinc.com/tppatch/)) does: he shortened earlier initialisation code to make room for his fixed calibration routine, as detailed in the `README` file in his archive. Andreas’ patch doesn’t increase `DelayCnt`’s size, it only ensures that the calibration routine doesn’t overflow; as a result, on fast CPUs the `Delay` routine might not wait as long as intended.

Another approach is used by [c’t’s patch](http://ss64.net/merlyn/pas-r200.htm#TP2): it relies on shortening another function in Crt (`Break`) to free up space for an improved version of `Delay`, and adjusting the divisor in the calibration routine so that the division no longer overflows. The calibration routine’s result isn’t used in this scenario.

There are also [a number of TSRs](http://www.reimagery.com/fsfd/system.htm#pascalfix) which will handle the problem at runtime, without patching; one significant difference here is that most (if not all) such TSRs won’t work with protected-mode Turbo Pascal programs. Here also there are number of different approaches. `PROT200` relies on handling the divide-by-zero error in the TSR instead of letting Borland’s code handle it. `TP7P5FIX` hooks the interrupt setup function in DOS and intercepts the initialisation code when it tries to setup its divide-by-zero handler, instead patching the initialisation code to return the highest possible value (0xFFFF). `R200FIX` patches dummy `OUT` instructions into the delay loop, which allows it to provide correct delays. (Thanks to [Michael Karcher](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/10479/michael-karcher) for the investigations.)

Comment: I've still got at least one customer using a patched TP application. They were going to switch to another vendor's Windows application years ago - but that turned out to be vaporware so they stuck with my DOS stuff and still use it to a limited extent today.

Comment: I still consider it an irony that run time error 200 was triggered by a CPU above 200 MHz. As if they wanted to tell the critical frequency right in the error message. :-)

Comment: The comment about the inner working of the TSRs is not accurate for all of them. I just checked TP7P5FIX and it instead patches the initialization code to replace the sequence "MOV CX, 55; DIV CX" by "MOV AX,FFFFh; NOP; NOP". I also checked PROT200, which indeed catches the divide-by-zero exception (and returns FFFF). And I checked R200FIX which patches an dummy `OUT` instruction into the timing loops. R200FIX is the only tool that keeps delays correct and contains the most elaborate (and memory-saving) TSR loading mechanism. None of these three tools can handle protected mode applications.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I’ve updated the comment in question (with some additional info on `TP7P5FIX`).

Comment: I still don't understand why they need to calculate the delay even though the user doesn't use anything related

Comment: J R Stockton’s page on the topic (http://ss64.net/merlyn/pas-r200.htm) is an amazing resource. Tremendous attention to detail and a ton of effort to track down available resources.

Comment: If the CRT unit is included, it will perform all the CRT unit initializations, including the delay calibration, even if delay procedure itself is not used. It does not know at compile time if whether delay procedure is called or not.

Comment: @phuclv Lazy initialisation wasn't required, so why do it? The cost wasn't trivial back then. It was much easier and more convenient to just do it in unit initialisation (note that he problem only happens if you link the CRT unit). In the end, would you really prefer the program to crash on its first delay rather than right at the start?

Comment: @Luaan: More to the point, if code e.g. turns on a sound, delays 50ms, and turns off the sound, would one want the first such operation to leave the sound on for longer than subsequent ones?

Comment: @Luaan the original designers surely didn’t consider that the delay function would crash. So reasoning about the point of time when the application will crash, surely wasn’t the original motivation for not initializing it lazily.

Comment: @Holger Yeah, that's why I was stuck for a few minutes whether to include the last sentence or not. I assumed it would be obvious enough that I'm not trying to imply this was a conscious decision on part of the designers beyond a general rule "fail early". That is, there's e.g. 10 things being initialised on startup. We're not expecting any of them to fail, but if one of them does, it's better to fail right then rather than have some completely unexpected inconsistency throughout the application.

Comment: @Justme: IIRC, TP's static linker (at least in later versions) was “smart” enough to identify which functions defined in a TPU were (potentially) called, so `delay`'s code itself wouldn't be included in your EXE if you never used it.  But it wouldn't optimize away *part* of a unit's initializer.

Comment: *the only way that a user's Pascal code can cause a divide overflow is by dividing by zero.*  Is that really true?  Does Pascal not allow you to do signed division of INT_MIN / -1, which [faults if done with x86's `cwd`  / `idiv` 16 / 16 => 16-bit division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378104/why-does-integer-division-by-1-negative-one-result-in-fpe/46378352)?  (That and divisor = 0  are the only cases where div or idiv can fault when you just zero- or sign-extend a dividend of the same width as the divisor.)  BTW, that signed overflow is why `INT_MIN / -1` is UB in C.

Comment: @Peter Pascal does, and Turbo Pascal does too, and that part of the explanation appears to be bogus. `var i : integer; i := -32768; WriteLn(i div -1);` produces `Error 200: Division by zero` in Turbo Pascal 5.5 on DOS.

Comment: The final paragraph of the quote seems to be entirely wrong; I've attempted to use BP7 on faster machines, and its IDE fails to start with the same message. Unless BP7's IDE uses the TP6 runtime?